# En React. Cannot read property 'addEventListener'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy empezando a hacer ejercicios con React y quise probar algo pequeño. En JS Vanilla me funciona bien, pero en React no quiere capturarlo y no entiendo.
Destacar que todo lo que corresponde ReactDom.render funciona correctamente

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

```html
function App() {


    let boton = document.querySelector("#boton");

   boton.addEventListener('click', () =>{
       document.querySelector("#mensaje").innerHTML="Hola a todos";
  })

  return (
   <div>
     <button id="boton">Enviar</button>
     <h1 id="mensaje">Mensaje</h1>
   </div>
    


  );
}

export default App;
```

Destacar que todo lo que corresponde ReactDom.render funciona correctamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu error es que el boton aun no ha sido renderizado lo cual es null. React js ofrece props en los elementos para que no tengas que hacer un addeventlistener ya que es dinamico y el elemento puede que no este renderizado.

```
<button onClick={(e)=>{

                  }}>Enviar</button>
```

Otra forma es que llames a tu elemento en el ciclo de vida del componenete cuando es montado "ComponentDidMount" en un componente funcional se usa useEffect con dependencia array vacio para simular el ComponentDidMount de un comp clase. Pero para manejar el doom en react recomienta obtener sus referencias con el prop ref del elemento. Asi obtienes el elemento sin llamar document.queryselector,etc..

Answer (score 0):

En reactjs no es buena practica utilizar referencias mediante el objeto `document`, simplemente puedes crear una función y mediante un atributo html asignar dicha función, e aquí un ejemplo

```
function App() {

 const handleFunction = () => {
  consol.log("works!!!")
  ...
 }

 return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFunction}>Enviar</button>
      <h1 >Mensaje</h1>
    </div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

de esta manera estamos creando una funcion de flecha y asignando la funcion al evento `onClcik` del boton

Answer (score 0):

Puede utilizar el hook useRef () de react. Para obtener más información, consulte la [Documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). Además, debes ponerlo en useEffect () o en componentWillMount (), depende si usas clases o funciones en tus componentes, para más información [Documentación](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

En el caso de que use funciones, en su componente:

```
  const boton = useRef(null);
  const mensaje = useRef(null);

  const handlerListener = () => {
      mensaje.current.innerHTML="Hola a todos";
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      boton.current.addEventListener("click", handlerListener );
      return(
         boton.current.removeEventListener("click", handlerListener );  
      );
  },[]);

  return (
   <div>
      <button ref={boton}>
        Okay
      </button>
      <h1 ref={mensaje}>Mensaje</h1>
   </div>
  );
}
```

Tenga en cuenta que en useEffect () pongo un retorno que se ejecutará cuando se desmonte el componente, de esta manera limpiamos el eventListener.

Aunque todo podria ser mas simple si usas el atibuto onClick, [Documentation](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
<button onclick={handler}>
  boton
</button>
```

Espero poder ayudarte, ¡buena suerte!

**EDIT**

Tambien puedes intentar algo como esto utilizando [findDOMNode](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode):

```
1) import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
2) const modalRef = useRef(null)
3) <div ref={modalRef}>
4)  useEffect(() => {
        if (modal) {
            const modalCloseBoton = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(modalRef.current).querySelector(".content a");
            function handlerClick() {
                setModal(false)
            }
            modalCloseBoton.addEventListener('click', handlerClick)
            return () => {
                modalCloseBoton.removeEventListener('click', handlerClick)
            }
        }
    })
```